# Execute code as different user in JSF Webapp

Tags: java, jsf, ejb

## Issue

I have some code that interacts with Weblogic JMX Beans to obtain a list of valid users.  This JMX calls require permission to access but I want to have this run for non-authenticated users.

My code setup is below and the fundamental question is whether `@RunAs` is the way I can achieve this and I just need to figure out the right place to put the mapping or whether I should be approaching this in a different way.

This is on Weblogic 12.2.1.4 and currently deployed as a war file

## Code

This is used to validate a form entry in a JSF page and this works well for authenticated users where I have created a JMX policy for the JMX bean but I want to extend this out to non-authenticated users.

I have a chain of classes that looks like

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBackingBean {

  @Inject
  private MyBusinessBean myBusBean;

  private List<String> users;

  public void listUsers() {
    users = myBusBean.listUsers();
  }
}
```

```
@RequestScoped
public class MyBusinessBean {
  
  @Inject
  private MyServiceBean myServBean;

  public List<String> listUsers() {
    return myServBean.listUsers();
  }
}
```

```
@RequestScoped
public class MyServiceBean {
  
  public List<String> listUsers() {
    // Some code here to accesss JMX bean
  }
}
```

## Problem

For a non-authenticated user the service method fails with `weblogic.management.NoAccessRuntimeException` which I can *"fix"* by adding a policy to allow public access to the JMX bean but I obviously would rather avoid that.

Digging around I believe I can tell Weblogic to call the methods as a different user using the `@RunAs` annotation?    I have been playing around with this with no joy.

AIUI the `@RunAs` annotation can only be used with EJB and not CDI managed beans so I changed the service bean to be

```
@Stateless
@RunAs("MyRunAsRole")
public class MyServiceBean
```

Which gets picked up as I see

> In EJB 'MyServiceBean' we could not determine a principal-name to use
> for the run-as-role 'MyRunAsRole'.  The weblogic-ejb-jar deployment
> descriptor or corresponding annotation has no run-as-principal-name...

but my attempts to map this have failed.   Adding

```
<security-role>
  <role-name>MyRunAsRole</role-name>
</security-role>
```

to web.xml and

```
<run-as-role-assignment>
  <role-name>MyRunAsRole</role-name>
  <run-as-principal-name>privUser</run-as-principal-name>
</run-as-role-assignment>
```

to weblogic.xml

still gives me the error about not being able to map to principal.

The `run-as-role-assignment` is definitely being read as when I forgot to add the role to web.xml it complained the security role did not exist.

I have also tried adding the `run-as-role-assignment` block into a weblogic-wjb-jar.xml file but that doesn't get picked up either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important bit was the fact this was packaged as a WAR file.

After some experimenting I got this working as above by placing a `weblogic-wjb-jar.xml` file in `WEB-INF` instead of `META-INF`

```
<weblogic-ejb-jar xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar  http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar/1.6/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd"> 
  <run-as-role-assignment>
    <role-name>MyRunAsRole</role-name>
    <run-as-principal-name>privUser</run-as-principal-name>
  </run-as-role-assignment>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

`@RolesAllowed` didn't work but that is another question...